# How to automatically update a MYSQL column value using formula and data from other columns in same row?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Question on mySQL.

I have a table with columns like below:

```
BasePrice, Discount, NetPrice
```

Now assume that the calculation of net price happens like below:

```
NetPrice = BasePrice - Discount
```

Now, I do not mind entering the `BasePrice` and `Discount` values into the column on my own, manually using phpMyadmin (that is, direct backend updation). Since the `NetPrice` value involves calculation as shown above, I do not want to update the column value for each row in the table, but would prefer the database updating it automatically for me ( `not that I am weak at math :)` ).

Is there someway to have the database update the `NetPrice` column value automatically? I know I can use php to get the other two column values, calculate and then update the `NetPrice` value, again using php code, but would prefer the db doing it on its own without any php/server side scripting.

I use mySQL and phpMyadmin for dev.

Thanks.

Comment: Example calculation:
BasePrice; Discount; NetPrice

1000;100;900

Comment: It is not good design to store NetPrice in your case as that yo can calculate at run time. So why to add an extra column in mysql table and keep headache of updating it.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a single query to update all table:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET NetPrice = BasePrice - Discount
```

or you can use a trigger to alter that column anytime a row is added.
Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER onInsert BEFORE INSERT ON `your_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.NetPrice = NEW.BasePrice - NEW.Discount;
END;
```

Comment: +1. An equivalent `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger would be needed to keep the NetPrice column "in sync" if the value of the BasePrice or Discount columns was modified by an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to Marco's (+1) answer, for just an INSERT, the simplest approach might be to reference columns assigned previously in the statement. For example:

```
INSERT INTO t (BasePrice, Discount, NetPrice) VALUES (17.00, 2.50, BasePrice-Discount);
```

For that NetPrice column to calculated correctly, the `BasePrice` and `Discount` columns must appear in the insert *before* the expression that calculates `NetPrice`. (The values assigned to each column is available later in the statement, *after* the column is assigned a value.)

If you always want to guarantee that NetPrice is kept "in sync" if either BasePrice or Discount is modified, then a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger will do that for you, so the combination of a `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger would be appropriate. (See the answer from Marco.)