# WordPress - Update Database Value in real time.

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have a piece of code that counts the lines of code within a wordpress site. I have successfully managed to send that number to the wordpress database so I can call on it in a different location in my theme files (this is because the script needs to be in the root of the install to count the lines of code).

Whilst this works really nicely, the BIG issue I have is that the number won't update itself automatically. i.e. the code for counting lines is www.mysite.com/loc.php and I mus go to this page and let it load before it updates the value in the database.

Is there a way to make it so that the value just automatically updates, so I don't have to navigate to the page for this to happen? i.e. when I add more lines of code, the value in the database updates itself.

Code for sending value to the db is as follows:

```
$num_of_lines = $folder -> count_lines();
update_option('line_count', $num_of_lines);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into jquery and ajax call

Wordpress provides for you the framework to call backend functions on the frontend
http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

another example:
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-ajax-with-php-on-your-wp-site-without-a-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a trigger, in order to update automatically MYSQL database

Look at this, i hope it will help
[How to automatically update a MYSQL column value using formula and data from other columns in same row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076971/how-to-automatically-update-a-mysql-column-value-using-formula-and-data-from-oth)